# How to run powershell script functions on different date intervals

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have created two functions in the Powershell script as below.

```
$date = Get-date
Write-Output $date.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy")

Function Oneday{
Param ($Name)
  Write-Output "This funtion will run everyday"
}


Function Fiveday{
Param ($Name)
  Write-Output "This funtion will run every 5 days"
}
```

My goal is to put this PowerShell script as a task scheduler and run the function 'Oneday' every day and function 'Fiveday' every 5 days. I tried to think of many ways by using function AddDays and all but couldn't get how can I achieve this task.

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulo/remainder operator (`%`) on the value of the `DayOfYear` property of the current date to only run on every 5th day:

```bsh
$date = Get-date
# Run every day
Oneday

if($date.DayOfYear % 5 -eq 0){
  # Only every 5th day
  Fiveday
}
```

---

To carry over multiple years, anchor against a starting date in the past:

```bsh
$start = Get-Date 2020-01-01
$date = Get-date
# Run every day
Oneday

if(($date - $start).Days % 5 -eq 0){
  # Only every 5th day
  Fiveday
}
```

Comment: I don't think so it can work. Suppose we have 366 days this year. Second last day on 365 the script should run for 'Fiveday' but for next year it should be run on 4th day as 1 day we have a carry over from this year.

Comment: @Virus you can carry it over, just anchor against a specific date instead of "start of current year". I've updated the answer :)